# How to "touch" a file in raw CMD without a touch command?

Tags: windows, cmd

At the good old Windows command prompt, I want to ensure a file exists and create it if it doesn't. I don't want to download any additional utilities (like touch) to accomplish this.

Comment: if you're running the command on Windows cmd then [it's **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). They have different capabilities and syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-liner solution:

As an example, I want to ensure a file named `App_Offline.htm` exists in my website root, but without overwriting that file if it already exists. This is the native DOS command I successfully used with append:

> (echo empty > nul) >> App_Offline.htm

Note the word `empty` can be any text you want because it is simply a dummy placeholder piped through nul and is lost; therefore no value is effectively appended to an existing file, and if a file doesn't already exist then it is created empty.

This solution did not update the Modified time stamp of the existing file.

Comment: I am sure this cannot work in MS-DOS since parenthesised command blocks are not supported there, also the file name is too long for MS-DOS. Do you actually mean the Window command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)? Anyway, what about `set _=>>file.ext`?

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, you're right - I corrected the question to tighten it up, was throwing around the terms too loosely.

Comment: and DOS doesn't support code blocks `()` so `(echo ...)` won't work